# Starting Intent Service from BroadcastReceiver - OnHandleEvent is never called

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android application and I have stumbled upon a problem for which I cannot seem to find a solution. I've tried different approaches, but with no luck. I am aware there are similar questions asked, but no answer seems to help. Here's the problem:

I am adding an action button to my notifications by adding the following line to my NotificationBuilder:

```
.addAction(R.drawable.done,"Complete", completeTaskPI)
```

Here's the code for the pending intent completeTaskPI:

```
Intent completeTask = new Intent(getActivity(),NotificationActionReceiver.class);
    completeTask.setAction("COMPLETE_TASK");
    completeTask.putExtra("taskId",taskId);
    PendingIntent completeTaskPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(),COMPLETE_TASK_CODE,completeTask,0);
```

It sends a broadcast to NotificationActionReceiver when the Action Button is clicked. From here, I simply start MyIntentService:

```
public class NotificationActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent completeTask = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);
    context.startService(completeTask);
    } 
}
```

Everything works properly before this moment. The receiver receives the pending intent with all the info and starts the service. The service starts, but never gets to onHandleIntent. The code for the IntentService:

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

public MyIntentService() {
    super("MyIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.i("onHandleIntent","triggered");
}

}
```

I've tried creating a new IntentService, a different BroadcastReceiver, still nothing. 
I'd like to note few things:
 - The service is properly declared in the Android Manifest;
 - I already have several other services that work just fine (with broadcast receiver, as well);
 - I need the action done on a background thread and not in the broadcast receiver;
 - I am assuming there is some problem with the context, although I am not sure what could be the problem.

I've been trying to locate the problem for several hours now and I just can't see it, so I thought I'd ask for help here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why dont you simply use `PendingIntent.getService` instead? why the indirect broadcast?

Comment: Fair point. Initially I didn't plan on using a service, but realized I needed one along the way. I guess I just got set in my way, trying to fix the problem with the BroadcastReceiver that I didn't even realize I could skip the 'middle man'. I believe this will fix the problem. I will give it a try right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @pskink's advice, I've solved the problem by starting the service with the pending intent, avoiding the Broadcast Receiver entirely. 
I hope this helps someone else in the future.
Thank you!